# lxml ignoring elements with undefined namespace prefix

Tags: python, namespaces, iterator, lxml

I've got some simple code stepping through a large XML file (containing entities defined in the DTD):

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse(
    file('t.xml', 'r'), etree.XMLParser(dtd_validation=False, load_dtd=True))
for e in tree.iter('bla'):
    process(e)  # whatever to be done with it
```

This works nicely for plain XML input.

Unfortunately the `iter` generator does not yield anything for tags with colons inside (namespace prefix).  The namespace is not defined anywhere, and actually I don't care about it.  I just want to iterate through the elements.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: I tired switching on validation, but that slowed down everything too much and used up all my memory (at least so it seemed); so I'd prefer a solution without validation turned on.

Comment: If the namespace isn't defined anywhere, that makes the content not valid XML. I'm surprised it parses at all.

Comment: Do you know what the undefined namespace prefixes will be ahead-of-time, or do you need a solution that works for any arbitrary prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this may not be entirely satisfying, but here is what I found:

```
>>> root = tree.getroot()
>>> root.attrib
{'{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}schemaLocation': 'http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml'}
>>> root.nsmap
{None: 'http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain', 'wls': 'http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls', 'sec': 'http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security', 'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'}
>>>
```

for a tag like:

```
<domain xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain"
    xmlns:sec="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security"
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml">
```

But this should allow you to get everything:

- "standard" attributes via `attrib`
- "namespace" ones through `nsmap`

Comment: That is interesting!  In my case I found out that the namespaces *were* defined after all.  I just was too blind to see it.  Now I can use the standard way of iter'ing through the properly namespaced tags.

But what you show here could be used for manipulation maybe and thus also parsing tags with namespace prefixes of undeclared name spaces, thus you'll get my thumbs-up for this one.